# Parsing an Atom document in android

Tags: android, xml, atom-feed

## Problem

I'm communicating to a REST API which uses an atom feed as responses.
This means I need to parse this.

## Solution

I want the solution to be as clean as possible.
Speed is a plus/low memory consumption is a plus but not really high priority.

#### Using a SAX parser

It'd be relativity easily to parse this myself, however it will probably break if I don't follow the Atom spec to the letter.

I will probably create something that will be hard to maintain on it's own and I'd rather avoid this.

#### Using a third party library

There seems to be quite a few out there that is written in java, some seems to maybe work in android but a lot of them are heavy and require lots of dependencies.

---

So, what's your take on this, any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest you break this down into separate questions. I realize that they are all related but the solution(s) are going to be rather verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not too difficult to use SAX to parse a subset of the Atom spec. You can ignore the elements that you are not interested in and process the important elements in a spec compliant manner.

The problem I have found with the 3rd party libraries is that they can be very very slow on Android, for the Atom I was parsing Rome was about 20x slower than my SAX parser.